# jdbc connection error-java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Tags: jdbc

I have a user in oracle, if I am selecting some data with the user in sqldeveloper its working fine
But when I am trying to connect to the same database and with the same username and password, I am getting error as java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

I can see the table exists in the database as I can query via sqldeveloper.

I tried searching forums but no answer yet. Do I need to give special permission to the user when connecting from Java (basically Java program using eclipse)

Comment: What if you use sqlplus command line?  I am very skeptical that your java code is using the same connection.

Comment: Getting the same error via sqlplus, ORA-00942: table or view does not exist. Not sure whats happening, kindly guide and help

Comment: Then the table you are referencing either does not have grants for this user or is missing a synonym.  If you execute "select * from user_tables" and don't see it, then that proves my point.

Comment: I am sorry if I am taking lot of time. My understanding is I need a table synonym to access the table, so I went ahead and created a public synonym for the table. Now I am not getting table/view does not exist error, but now error I am getting is ORA-01775: looping chain of synonyms.   Tried very hard to resolve but failed